Formatting of Date, DateTime, DateTimeOffset in ILogger
I've have a custom ILoggerProvider.  The implementation isn't important.  My issue is that any Date, DateTime, DateTimeOffset parameters that get passed to ILogger are converted by an internal Microsoft.Logging.Extensions.LogValuesFormatter class to a string using InvariantCulture instead of the CurrentCulture of the application.  We're in the UK and we use dd/MM/yyyy and not MM/dd/yyyy (Invariant). Even yyyy-MM-dd is much more preferable than the US-centric format.
The issue appears in the below sample's void Log<TState> method where TState state is an internal Microsoft.Logging.Extensions.LogValuesFormatter class that the format provide cannot crack open - only pass it into the provided "formatter".  Is there a way for me to provide an alternative to LogValuesFormatter class?  Those providers that log rich parameter logging do it so I should be able to do this with our own logger.
Its been suggested that I should look at ILogger accessing params args in the function Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel as a solution but these solutions all have serious downsides: a) uses reflection (slow and doesn't work with .net7+), b) cast state to IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) (doesn't work because the class is internal), c) serialise and deserialise the state to/from JSON (incredibly inefficient and only gets you so far), or d) implement your own LogInformation extension method (requires recoding 100s of log entries in various downlevel apps) and breaks portability with generic ILogger functionality.
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Text;

namespace XXXXX.Base;

/// <summary>
/// Custom ILoggerProvider, writes logs to text files with the option to cycle the filename daily.
/// Daily File change is checked and handled by a call to CustomFileLoggerProvider.CheckTimeToChangeFile()
/// which for efficiency should be done via an occasional background worker or a Scoped Page Request (middleware)
/// </summary>
[ProviderAlias("CustomFile")]
public sealed class CustomFileLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomFileLogger> _loggers = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    private CustomFileLoggerConfiguration _currentConfig;
    private readonly IDisposable? _onChangeToken;
    private readonly object _lock = new();
    private StreamWriter? _logFileWriter;
    private bool _stopLogging = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// If messages come in prior to initialisation via the first request (middleware) then stores values here
    /// </summary>
    private readonly List<string> _initialCache = new(32);

    public CustomFileLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<CustomFileLoggerConfiguration> config)
    {
        _currentConfig = config.CurrentValue;
        _onChangeToken = config.OnChange(config => _currentConfig = config);
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        _logFileWriter?.Flush();
    }

    public void Write(string text)
    {
        if (_stopLogging)
            return;

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_logFileWriter is null)
            {
                OpenLogFile();
                if (_logFileWriter is null)
                {
                    if (_initialCache.Count < 100)
                        _initialCache.Add(text);
                    else
                        _stopLogging = true;
                }
            }
            if (_logFileWriter is not null)
            {
                _logFileWriter.WriteLine(text);
                _logFileWriter.Flush();
            }
        }
    }



    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) =>
        _loggers.GetOrAdd(categoryName, name => new CustomFileLogger(categoryName, Write));

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens a new log file.  This should be called while under lock.
    /// </summary>
    private bool OpenLogFile()
    {
        var filename = _currentConfig.LogFile;
        if (filename is null)
            return false;

        try
        {
            _logFileWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, append: true, encoding: Encoding.UTF8);
            _logFileWriter.WriteLine();
            _logFileWriter.WriteLine();
            _logFileWriter.WriteLine($"======== {DateTime.UtcNow:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} ========");
            _logFileWriter.Flush();
            _stopLogging = false;
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
        ...
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the current log file.  This should be called while under lock.
    /// </summary>
    private void CloseLogFile(string reason)
    {
        if (_logFileWriter is not null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reason))
                _logFileWriter.WriteLine(reason);
            _logFileWriter.WriteLine("======== END ========");
            _logFileWriter.Flush();
            _logFileWriter.Dispose();
            _logFileWriter = null;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            CloseLogFile("Closing Log File due to Provider being disposed (e.g. application shutdown)");
            _loggers.Clear();
            _onChangeToken?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Custom ILogger, writes logs to text files
/// </summary>
public sealed class CustomFileLogger(string categoryName, Action<string> writeFunc) : ILogger
{
    private readonly string _categoryName = categoryName;
    private readonly Action<string> _writeFunc = writeFunc;

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull => default!;

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) =>
        // Ensure that only information level and higher logs are recorded
        logLevel >= LogLevel.Information;

    public void Log<TState>(
        LogLevel logLevel,
        EventId eventId,
        TState state,
        Exception? exception,
        Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        // Ensure that only information level and higher logs are recorded
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
            return;

        // Get the formatted log message
        var message = formatter(state, exception);

        //var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        //Write log messages to text file
        _writeFunc($"{LL(logLevel)} [{_categoryName}] {message}");
    }

    private static string LL(LogLevel l) => l switch
    {
        LogLevel.Information => "INF",
        LogLevel.Trace => "TRC",
        LogLevel.Debug => "DBG",
        LogLevel.Warning => "WRN",
        LogLevel.Error => "ERR",
        LogLevel.Critical => "CRITICAL",
        LogLevel.None => "",
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(l))
    };
}

/// <summary>
/// By convention, extension methods on ILoggingBuilder are used to register the custom provider
/// </summary>
public static class CustomFileLoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILoggingBuilder AddCustomFileLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddConfiguration();
        builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider, CustomFileLoggerProvider>());
        LoggerProviderOptions.RegisterProviderOptions<CustomFileLoggerConfiguration, CustomFileLoggerProvider>(builder.Services);
        return builder;
    }

    public static ILoggingBuilder AddCustomFileLogger(this ILoggingBuilder builder, Action<CustomFileLoggerConfiguration> configure)
    {
        builder.AddCustomFileLogger();
        builder.Services.Configure(configure);
        return builder;
    }
}


You seem to log without a ready to use 3rd party logger. Your code does not show logging a datetime so i can just say that the stuff that gives you a date to log should have a ToString method where you can specify the format you want with a formatprovider. A culture is a formatprovider. So a sample DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(MyLovelyPredefinedCultureInfoWIthWishedDateTimeFormat).

Hi @Ralf, its our own custom logger rather than a 3rd party one.  The issue is that our apps pass in DateTime types into ILogger.LogInformation() calls but by the time it arrives at our custom logger (void Log<TState>() method), the logger message and associated parameters have already been converted to a single string and the chosen culture used for the DateTime is wrong.  I can't go through dozens of applications and 100s of lines of code to pass in a string version of the datetime - nor would I want to - the data is DateTime not a string and should be passed into the logger as such.

Okay, I've just realised, that the incoming TState message isn't a string but some kind of formatter with the parameters and message still split out and it is just the "ToString()" that is formatting with InvariantCulture.  So now I'm think I need to change or implement a custom version of Microsoft.Logging.Extensions.LogValuesFormatter?  Where do I customise this?

Please edit your question accordingly or ask a new one.

That stuff is hard coded in the extension methods like LogInformation. If you want to change that behavior you need to roll you own Extension method that does something different before handing things over to your Log message. Internally this class is used.

This question is similar to: ILogger accessing params args in the function Log(LogLevel logLevel. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@jeb done, thanks.

@BurnsBA.  I've looked into your suggested post.  There are at least 4 solutions put forward but all have serious downsides (or no longer work, even in principal).  I've updated my question with a paragraph detailing these.  Thanks.

TState is the internal class Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.FormattedLogValues, but you access the parameters by explicitly casting to (IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)state.
